# How to ignore @Indexed annotation for Spring Data Mongo

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have multiple projects that use the same class User which has the following annotation:

```
@Indexed(direction=IndexDirection.DESCENDING)
    private Date created = null;
```

I don't want each project to generate a call to mongo to create the index as this causes issues (e.g. if I want to change the index).

Is there a way to ask Spring Data Mongo to ignore the @Indexed annotation via the configuration file (or other way)?

Comment: Just curious, why you keep the @Indexed annotations if they are to be ignored? Is it solely for documentation purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming Spring Data MongoDB 2.2 allows to turn off annotated index creation via `MongoConfigurationSupport#autoIndexCreation` or directly by calling `mongoMappingContext.setAutoIndexCreation(false)`.

Please see the [reference documentation for 2.2.0.RC1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#mapping-usage) for more details.

Comment: Does that mean in Spring Boot V2.2.2.RELEASE, autoIndexCreation is true by default and if we want true, then we dont need to change anything ? Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003179/please-use-mongomappingcontextsetautoindexcreationboolean-or-override-mong